# Multiple ComboBox with single DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 combo boxes that are tied up to a single binding source in a dataset. When I select an item in one of the combo boxes, they both change. I don't have code in the combobox themselves but I do have the dataset fill:

```
this.cLIENT_BranchesTableAdapter.Fill(this.gcDataSet.CLIENT_Branches);
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give each ComboBox their own BindingSource:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(source, string.Empty);
comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(source, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Wait, how about the display member and value member? will that be in the parameter?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay Those properties can stay the same.  The data is still pointing to the same data table.  The BindingSource does not need those parameters.

Comment: I see, so I can still set the value member in the binding mode in the designer? is that right?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay I never use the designer for those things, but I think you would just create two separate binding sources and then use each binding source for each combo box.  I prefer to have the designer do as little work for me as possible.

Comment: I've seen other answers suggesting to clone the data source itself: `comboBox1.DataSource = source; comboBox2.DataSource = new List<string>(source);`, but creating separate `BindingSources`, like this solution suggest, is more efficient, especially if the source collection is big.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue.

```
combobox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```