# DataGridView and ListBox that have the same DataSources selecting the same element

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I have a dataGridView and a listBox that have the same datasource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.tUsuario;
listBox1.DataSource = db.tUsuario;
```

The problem is, when I click on dataGridView element, this element also shows as the one selected on the listBox, and the same happens  vice versa. Why does this happen? Is there anyway to deatach this behaviour from the two?

Comment: See [Multiple ComboBox with single DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109052/719186)

Comment: Or [Bind multiple ComboBox to a single List - Issue: When I choose an item, all combo boxes change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865838/3110834)